# regex to remove words starting with string

Tags: r, regex, text, text-mining, regular-language

I am working on a text mining case in R and I need to remove from my Corpus all the words that start with https.
I am still learning regex so your help will be much appreciated!

I am trying to remove all the https(and subsequent string until the space) for the following:

haciendo  principales httpstcotogmdfcq felicidades rodrigo equipo  madre   nominación   oscars  cine español   enh httpstcopupepkzwx    pasando  cataluña  insostenible  sociedad catalana  rehén   supremacistas   desar httpstcojzgilkyx   auténtica broma  sánchez critique  acuerdo  pp  andalucía   pactado  torra   apel httpstcofwevrjfpsv  puede ser     roto  espacio electoral  tres partidos  siquiera hablen  ponerse  acuerdo httpstcoydkjmydxhc  gobierno socialista   ningún proyecto  españa   quedarse   moncloa solo quiere mantener  httpstcoqwibvkxl allá   gobernado  ppopular  transformado  bien  vida   españoles  preparados  go httpstcocdntnstbpa  partido político    objetivo   mismo

Comment: `grep("^https", words, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)`, where `words` is the name of your vector / column.

Comment: Please add a sample of the data for which the `regex` is required.